# Groups with special automorphism group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, reference-request

I am looking for all finite groups $G$ such that for each subgroup $H$ of $G$ and each automorphism $\sigma$ of $H$ there exists an automorphism $\psi$ of $G$ whose restriction to $H$ is $\sigma$. Is there any reference on this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These groups are called the groups of *injective type*.
It is known that nonabelian finite groups of injective type have even order.

See the following papers: 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0017089512000031

http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0219498807002235

Comment: You are welcome @majid-arezoomand